no me permite acceder a la propiedad
tengo un problema, no me permite acceder a la propiedad nombre, en la imagen pueden ver que existe. lo comprobé haciendo: {{$t->producto}}

                $top = ProductosVendidos::with('producto')
                ->select('producto_id', DB::raw('SUM(cantidad) as total'))
                ->groupBy('producto_id')
                ->orderBy('total', 'DESC')
                ->get();

Vista Blade:
 @foreach ($top as $t)

      <div class="font-weight-bolder">{{$t->producto->nombre}}</div>

 @endforeach

Error:
Attempt to read property "nombre" on null

El error que te está devolviendo es porque estás haciendo:
$t->producto->nombre

Y en ese caso producto es null, y por eso te da el error.
Al realizar la siguiente query en el select le estás diciendo que te devuelva solo el product_id y la suma de las cantidades pero no estás devolviendo nada del producto.
$top = ProductosVendidos::with('producto')
                ->select('producto_id', DB::raw('SUM(cantidad) as total'))
                ->groupBy('producto_id')
                ->orderBy('total', 'DESC')
                ->get();

Una posible correción sería:
$top = ProductosVendidos::with('producto')
                ->select('producto_id', DB::raw('SUM(cantidad) as total'), 'producto.nombre as nombre_producto')
                ->groupBy('producto_id')
                ->orderBy('total', 'DESC')
                ->get();


Entendi el error, pero ahora me da el siguiente: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'producto.nombre' in 'field list'

@jeremiasrosas Si sigues esta respuesta prueba con $t->producto->nombre_producto, pues te lo ha cambiado a esto: 'producto.nombre as nombre_producto', a ver si cuela.
